# How to Solve the Error OpenGLES is deprecated. Consider migrating to Metal instead

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am using unity 2019.4.21f1. In ios build settings i have choose in OpenGles2(Depracated) and OpenGles3(Deprecated) in Graphics Api.

When i try to Archive the build it receives the error

```
OpenGLES is deprecated. Consider migrating to Metal instead.
```

is there any way to byepass the error or able to solve it.

can any one can give solutions for this

Thanks n advance

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as it says on the tin: OpenGL has longer supported on iOS for many years now. You have to use Metal.